# Cannot register for push notifications - iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Since today (27.04.2016), delegate methods for push notifications are never called.

Both registration methods are implemented, but not called

After check on apsd logs I notice, that there is a SSL handshake failure, and that is only thing from apsd process

```
Apr 27 15:52:05 iPad apsd[92] <Warning>: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
Apr 27 15:52:05 iPad apsd[92] <Notice>: 2016-04-27 15:52:05 +0300 apsd[92]: <APSCourier: 0x156873f0>: Stream error occurred for <APSCourierConnection: 0x15675ee0> onInterface NonCellular: TLS Error Code=-9806 "connection closed due to error"
```

Edit  : Happens only on sandbox. Production works fine.

Edit 2: IMO, that looks like a problem in Apple servers, but cannot be sure.

Edit 3: Get one iOS 8.1.3 device.There methods are called.

Comment: The push servers are currently indicated as being up, does it work now if you try again? https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Several other people are reporting having problems with the sandbox starting in the last 12 hours or so, seems like its obviously something gone wrong on the Apple side despite what their system monitor says about the status.  No idea how it can be brought to Apple's attention if they are not already aware of it.

Comment: I was thinking to report a bug, but they say in Tech note, that this could happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was connectivity issues to Apple side.
Now (28.04.16) it is working.

Comment: Hi, me to facing same issue in  ios 9.3. when i app open its asking pushnotification permission  alert and i gave Ok, After i am switching to iphone device settings --> My app --> Notification  status is OFF, But i gave Ok button  while app open. But its happened some times only. not all case